# Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons error with JSON,stringify

Tags: reactjs

I have a modal dialog where I want to display following JSON.

```
{
"id": 8,
"accountId": 2844,
"tagName": null,
"mediaType": "xx",
"disguise": true,
"inserted": "2020-01-31T09:48:38.763",
"status": "Failed",
"started": "2020-01-31T14:26:17.16",
"completed": null,
"durationInMs": null,
"retryCount": 3,
"error": "The remote server returned an error: (404) Object Not Found.",
"publicIp": null,
"statusId": 2,
"mediaTypeId": 1
}
```

I display it in the modal body with following snippet:

```
<pre className="layout__item u-1/2-lap-and-up">   {JSON.stringify(props.job, null, 2)} </pre>
```

When running the snippet the JSON is displayed as expected. However when I close the modal I get following error.

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If
>   you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `movementY` on a
>   released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you
>   must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist()

If I remove JSON.stringify(props.job, null, 2) there is no error. Any pointers? I can see a lot of articles about cylendric JSON, but my json is plain and simple.

Comment: I think we can use `<pre>{json content}</pre>`, here, right

Comment: <pre className="layout__item u-1/2-lap-and-up">{json props.job}</pre> this fails with "expected token missing"?

Comment: please refer this https://medium.com/trabe/react-syntheticevent-reuse-889cd52981b6

Comment: I read that. But my challenge I am not using any events. I just pass a parameter to my child: <Modal isOpen={showDetailsModal} toggle={toggleDetails} size="lg">
          <ModalHeader toggle={toggleDetails}>Details</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <DetailsTable job={detailsData}></DetailsTable>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>. And then display it. So no events going on. The only event id when react straps modal closes, and I dont control that event. And that is when it is happening.

Comment: ooh, can you make a stackblitz demo reproducing the error

Comment: Actually your link redirected my to the error. In my toggle event from the modal I had some async calls. I have no idea how this related to the JSON.stringify(props.job, null, 2). But allocating the toggle function to only show and hide my modal worked. Can you add an answer with the link you suggested.

Comment: sure bro. will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These type of errors are explained in the article, please take a look at

[Refer the article](https://medium.com/trabe/react-syntheticevent-reuse-889cd52981b6)